# Find the solutions to ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }=2$

Tags: trigonometry

Find solutions to, 
$${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }=2$$
where $0≤x≤8π$

Since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are in powers hence $450$ and $273$ will never be zero for any $x$. So I took $$(\sin x)^{ 3 }=0$$ and $$(\cos x)^{ 5 }=0$$
and thus I got $5$ solutions in $[0, 8π]$.
Is it correct?

Comment: So what should be the correct approach?

Comment: The sine and cosine cannot be simultaneously $0$, so the above is not right.

Comment: @Hyperbola your question is find the number of solutions or find the solutions?

Comment: Every number is this equation is weird.

Comment: The original question asked to find the number of solutions only.

Comment: Number of solution is 8, as can be seen from this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=450%5E%28Sin%5Bx%5D%29%5E3+%2B+273%5E%28Cos%5Bx%5D%29%5E5+-+2%2C+x%3D0..8Pi%2C+y%3D-0.1..0.1&a=*C.0-_*NumberMath-).

Comment: @Hyperbola Can you explain what class this is homework for? That might give a hint of how to proceed.

Comment: Pre-University level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, so it suffices to find all solutions in $[0,2\pi)$, then add multiples of $2\pi$ to get the rest.

If $x$ is a solution, then $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ must have opposite signs.   This is true because $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can't both be zero, so if they are both nonnegative then ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }>2$, while if they are both nonpositive then ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }<2$.  Therefore, all solutions in $[0,2\pi)$ are also in $(\pi/2,\pi)\cup(3\pi/2,2\pi)$.

There is at least one solution in each of the intervals $(\pi/2,\pi)$ and $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$.  This can be seen by evaluating ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }$ when $x=\pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2, 2\pi$, and noticing that it is respectively $>2,<2,<2,>2$, and applying the Intermediate Value Theorem.

There is at most one solution in each of the intervals $(\pi/2,\pi)$ and $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$.  This can be seen by observing that ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }$ is strictly decreasing on $(\pi/2,\pi)$, and strictly increasing on $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$.

By translating these two solutions by multiples of $2\pi$, there are altogether $8$ solutions in $[0,8\pi]$.

---

Here is an explanation of why ${ 450 }^{ { (\sin x) }^{ 3 } }+{ 273 }^{ { (\cos x) }^{ 5 } }$ is decreasing on $(\pi/2,\pi)$.  If $b>1$, then $b^x$ is an increasing function of $x$.  If $k$ is an odd positive integer, then $x^k$ is an increasing function of $x$.  On the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$, $\sin(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$.  The composition of a decreasing function with increasing functions is decreasing, so $$x\mapsto \sin x\mapsto (\sin x)^3\mapsto 450^{(\sin x)^3}$$ is decreasing on $(\pi/2,\pi)$.  Similarly, $273^{(\cos x)^5}$ is decreasing on that interval, and a sum of two decreasing functions is decreasing.  (I haven't given proofs here, but I've broken it down to simpler statements that do have elementary proofs.)  The reason the function is increasing on $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$ is similar; $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both increasing on that interval.

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation of the strictly increasing / decreasing part? Did you just take the differential? I got up to there, and then didn't want to differentiate.

Comment: No, no derivatives needed, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I didn't think of the function composition. Though, you'd likely want to get rid of $k$ an (odd positive) integer, since it's likely not an integer, and then just focus on $0 < \sin x < 1$ or $-1 < \sin x < 0$.

Comment: @Calvin: The values of $k$ I had in mind, relevant to the problem, are $3$ and $5$.  I don't understand your comment but that hints to me that I probably wasn't clear that I'm referring to the composition $y=\sin(x)$, $z=y^3$, $w=450^z$.

Comment: Ahhhhh ... I was wondering why you switched from $b^x$ to $x^k$. That's much easier to understand now.